# regex to match the first lookbehind only

Tags: regex

I have the following reports. Some have this:

```
Symptom Correlation to Reflux
Table 
Symptom Correlation to Reflux
Table 
Reflux Symptom Index 
Table
```

and some have this:

```
Symptom Correlation to Reflux
Table 
Reflux Symptom Index 
Table
```

I want to only ever capture the Table between `Symptom Correlation to Reflux` and `Reflux Symptom Index`.

How can I do a positive lookbehind and only match to the first `Symptom Correlation to Reflux` and capture the table within that match- I guess with a non greedy operator for the positive lookbehind

Is it something like (which doesn't work):

```
.*?(?<=Reflux Symptom Index)Symptom Correlation to Reflux
```

Comment: Do you have positive lookahead available in your regex engine? Your regex does not take into account newlines, could that be the reason it doesn't match ?

Comment: Sorry. I'm using java so I can take account of newlines and I can use positive lookahead too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you can use this regex with negative lookahead:

```
(?s)\bSymptom Correlation to Reflux\b((?:(?!Symptom Correlation to Reflux).)*?)\bReflux Symptom Index\b
```

**Java code:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
"(?s)\\bSymptom Correlation to Reflux\\b((?:(?!Symptom Correlation to Reflux).)*?)\\bReflux Symptom Index\\b");
```

`table` is available in captured group #1

`(?:(?!Symptom Correlation to Reflux).)*?` is negative lookahead assertion to ensure that we don't match another `Symptom Correlation to Reflux` in the middle of start/end.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zY7vT9/3)

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You may apply this regex:

```
/(?<=\bSymptom Correlation to Reflux\b).*(?=\bReflux Symptom Index\b)/s
```

It matches between the first occurrence of `Symptom Correlation to Reflux` until the first occurrence of `Reflux Symptom Index`. Pay attention to the `s` matching parameter which has `.` match newlines (not the default).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this pattern:

```
/(?<=\bSymptom Correlation to Reflux\b\n)(\S+)\s*(?=\bReflux Symptom Index\b)/g
```

[REGEX 101 DEMO.](https://regex101.com/r/nI1sI4/4)